# Rails 4.2 syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have two computers that I mainly use to develop my Rails application.  While working on Computer 1, I added some bootstrap elements to some inputs.  For example:

```
= f.select :transport_from_state, options_for_select(state_populator, @invoice_ambulance.transport_from_state), { include_blank: true}, { class: 'chosen-select', 'data-placeholder': 'State' }
```

I added the `'data-placeholder': 'State'` and used the 'newer' syntax instead of the old `:data-placeholder' => 'State'` which works fine. The page works with no errors on Computer 1.

I pulled down on computer 2, and now I am getting an error for every instance of `'data-placeholder'`.   Here is my error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
...en-select', 'data-placeholder': 'State' }
```

I can replace it with the old syntax and it works fine.  However, I shouldn't have to switch 100 instances of this to a deprecated syntax. I have since bundle installed, bundle updated, and rebuilt the db with no luck.

Computer 1 (works)

ruby 2.2.0p0

Rails 4.2.0

Computer 2 (doesnt work)

ruby 2.2.0preview1

Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 8):

You need to upgrade Computer 2 to the real Ruby 2.2.0 rather than this beta-ish "preview" version you have. Using quoted symbols with the JavaScript-style trailing colon syntax:

```
{ 'some string': value }
```

wasn't valid before Ruby 2.2, the 2.2.0preview1 version you have on Computer 2 apparently doesn't support it.

---

BTW, there is no *old* and *new* syntax, there is an alternate JavaScript-style notation that can be use when the keys in a Hash-literal are *some* symbols. Whoever told you that the hashrocket is deprecated is, at best, confused.

Answer (score 4):

The "newer" syntax is only for symbols.

`{hello: 'world'}` is equivalent to `{:hello => 'world'}` but if your key is a string then you still have to use the "hash rocket" syntax: {'hello' => 'world'}

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html

Comment: In Ruby 2.2 `{ 's': ... }` is valid and will give you a key of `:s`. Quoted symbols required the hashrocket and leading-colon before 2.2.

Comment: I assumed incorrectly that my ruby 2.1.5 install was still relevant. Thanks @muistooshort